# Can I constrain a vertex to never move beyond specific coordinates?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, coordinates

So, when editing I would love to be able to move my vertices around but make sure they never go below a certain plane - for instance, make sure I can't move them below a Z-value of 0. Is there any way to do this, while still having the freedom to move the vertex in all 3 directions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not limit vertex transformation in Edit mode.